# LRUcache behaviour in python

Tags: python

I am using LRUCache from cachetools to store some data in form of dict, i am having a hard time understanding the behaviour of the missing factory concept, can someone help?

```
GivenQuestionsCache=LRUCache(maxsize=100,missing=getGivenQuestions)
def getGivenQuestions(studentId):
    cur=db.cursor()
    cur.execute(*query*)
    questions={}
    for each in cur.fetchall():
        if(int(each[1]) in questions):
            questions[int(each[1])].append([each[3],each[4]])
        else:
            questions[int(each[1])]=[[each[3],each[4]]]
    return questions
```

now, when i do

```
print(GivenQuestionsCache[studentId])
```

i expect something like

```
[[211736, None], [211736, 'a'], [207113, 'a'], [219556, None], [207095, None], [89027, None], [89027, None]]
```

but it prints

```
{1: [[211736, None], [211736, 'a'], [207113, 'a'], [219556, None], [207095, None], [89027, None], [89027, None]]}
```

why is it also printing key along with the value?
Also, because of this, i am unable to use append like this

```
GivenQuestionsCache[studentId].append([int(questionId),None])
```

Comment: `getGivenQuestions` is returning a `dict`, so that's why the `LRUCache` is populated with dictionaries. The `1` you see is the value of `int(each[1])`.

Comment: Yes, if that's the case GivenQuestionsCache[1].append([int(questionId),None]) should work right?
but it doesn't, throws the error- ''dict' object has no attribute 'append''

Comment: No. In your implementation, `GivenQuestionsCache` is a `dict` of `dict` (`LRUCache` is a `dict` where the keys are the `studentId`, and the method you provide to populate missing keys returns a `dict` where the keys are formed from `each[1]`). Your accessing only the first dict. If you'd share the meaning of your query we could give some more detailed advice on a better data structure.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: yes i was able to. i had to use GivenQuestionsCache[studentId][studentId].append([int(questionId),None])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was dict of dict of nested dicts which was causing the issue, i solved this using `GivenQuestionsCache[studentId][studentId].append([int(questi‌​onId),None])`